# Contains-comparison in array does not work

Tags: powershell

I have this array

```
$jobStatusResults.GetType();

IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     Object[]  System.Array
```

That contains

```
$jobStatusResults

Value    
-----    
Succeeded
Succeeded
Succeeded
Succeeded
Failed   
Succeeded
```

But my comparison statement does not work

```
($jobStatusResults.Contains('Failed'))
False
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are accessing an array of custom objects instead an array of values. You need to access the `Value` property first. `$jobstatusresults.value -contains 'Failed'`

Comment: Fantastic, that solved it! Can you put it as a reply so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: It has been posted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing an array of custom objects instead an array of values. You need to access the Value property first.

```
$JobStatusResults.Value -contains 'Failed'
```